# databinding DataGrid to a List<object[]>

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `List<object[]> MyCollection` which is a result of a `SELECT` SQL query.
Each `object[]` represents a row in the query result, and the length of the array will vary for different queries.
I have the name of the column headers in a separate `List<string> MyHeaders`.

I want to databind `MyCollection` to a `DataGrid` with the header of the columns from `MyHeaders`, and autogenerate the columns.

The reason I want to use `AutoGenerateColumns` is because I want the `Datagrid` to reconize the DataTypes of each object, and use the appropriate Column Templates for each DataType.

Thanks!

Comment: I think DataGrid would make a better tag than dynamic. I'm curious about the solution too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck and need to get on: use a dataset/ datatable. Ancient but they still work fine! If you want to know if it can be done, i don't know. Most examples of binding to an IList I've seen manually loop and create columns.

Regards GJ

Comment: I felt somewhat gulity using Datatable, but decided to use it. it seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: LOL yeah I know, they don't feel MVVMy/Linqy, but I do think they're not getting enough love lately ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a list for the headers, use a dictionary and use the property names as the keys and put the description as the values.  Do a normal blah.DataSource = List and DataBind().  In your itemdatabound event replace the headers with your description by searching the dictionary with something like this:

`foreach col in grid.Columns
{
    col.Name = dic[col.Name].Value;
}`